# Automatically updated graph in jupyter notebook using qt5

Tags: python, matplotlib, qt5, jupyter

how to do this in jupyter notebook:

```
%matplotlib notebook
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

m = 100
n = 100
matrix = np.random.normal(0,1,m*n).reshape(m,n)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
plt.ion()

fig.show()
fig.canvas.draw()

for i in range(0,100):
   #ax.clear()
   plt.plot(matrix[i,:])
   fig.canvas.draw()
```

but using "%matplotlib qt5" instead of "notebook"?

When I try it it show the figure only after the loop is ended. I would like to see it updating every plot.

Answer (score 0):

In principle you can do the following in interactive mode:

```
%matplotlib qt4
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

m = 100
n = 100
matrix = np.random.normal(0,1,m*n).reshape(m,n)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
plt.ion()

plt.draw()


for i in range(0,30):
   #ax.clear()
   plt.plot(matrix[i,:])
   plt.draw()
   plt.pause(0.1)
plt.ioff()
plt.show()
```

However, it might crash in jupyter after finishing the loop, due to Qt being used.
It should however work, when using the tk backend, `%matplotlib tk`.

You might want to consider using a `FuncAnimation` instead of interactive mode. While this would suffer from the same limitations with Qt in Jupyter I find it more intuitive to use a function for updating the plot and there is no need to redraw the canvas manually.

```
%matplotlib tk
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation 

m = 100
n = 100
matrix = np.random.normal(0,1,m*n).reshape(m,n)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)


def update(i):
    #ax.clear()
    plt.plot(matrix[i,:])

ani = matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update, frames=30, repeat=False)
plt.show()
```

I asked a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44028406/matplotlib-animation-with-qt-backend-in-jupyter) on why this would no work with the qt backend.